# What type of hash (or encryption) is this?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, hash

I am reverse engineering an unfortunate legacy application. I know the following:

`username` => hashFunction() => `8BYUW6iFeL9mmSBW7xjzMw~~`

`password` => hashFunction() => `VszQfe5n0+CooePc7CS9kw~~`

The hashes always seem to be 22 characters in length. The system is a legacy microsoft .net application. I have reason to believe that they are reverseable as well (but this may not be true).

The two trailing tildes make me feel like I should be able to identify this. How do I begin to figure out what type of hashing is used?

Comment: Are all hashes 22 characters in length?

Comment: It may be a base-64 encoding of a hash.

Comment: 22 characters of Base64 equates to 128 bits.  Your first look should be to try MD5 hashing.  MD5 is probably right for a legacy application as well.

Comment: Come to think of it, it might be simply an mixed, alternative base 64 encoding of the username and the password as well.

Answer (score 2):

If the 'hashFunction' function is part of the legacy application, you could use a reflection tool like .net reflector to reverse the code to see what the function is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Just a wild guess

```
64^21  <  2^128  <=  64^22
```

You need 22 characters for a base-64 encoding of a 128-bit hash.

The above argument will also work if you replace 64 with any integer from 57 up to 68. Base-67 encodings are not common I assume but it doesn't harm to have that in mind.

Your samples seem to have at least 63 characters (26 upper, 26 lowercase, 10 digits, plus the plus-sign).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the trailing '~' characters are fillers (which is not the usual case (the usual is '=')) the username comes out to:

```
f0 16 14 5b a8 85 78 bf 66 99 20 56 ef 18 f3 33
```

and the password comes out to:

```
56 cc d0 7d ee 67 d3 e0 a8 a1 e3 dc ec 24 bd 93
```

in hex.  This agrees with the the 128 bits of the other posters.  It sounds like the output of an AES-128 encryption or MD5 hash.  With a sample this small and no idea what the source was, this is kind of where we have to leave it.  Since you said you thought they might be reversible, that kind of points to AES-128.  Without a bigger sample and no input data, that is all that can be done with it.

I tried doing an MD5 hash of the strings "username" and "password" and they come out to different values.  If it was encrypted with AES, we are out of luck without some more hints.

Good luck,
/Bob Bryan

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting value:

```
Fj83STvXE+6q57GVjIi9aQ==
```

I just happen to know it is PI to 37 places (times 1E37)

```
3141592653589793238462643383279502884
```

Not all base64 values are hashed or encrypted.  Without some knowledge of the process that resulted in the value, it is impossible to do much with a random 128 bit string.

Regards,
/Bob Bryan